# Javascript, add string if true

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, addition

I need to modify this function:

```
function checkPermissions(fid, obj) {

$("#permissions_"+fid+"_canview").attr("checked", obj.checked);

}
```

if the param "n" is "true" then instead of #permissions it'll output #permissionsSet.

is that possible?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP clarified the question to be change this whether or not a 3rd parameter was provided.  Here you go.

```
function checkPermissions(fid, obj, n) {
  var id = n !== undefined ? '#permissionsSet' : '#permissions';
  $(id + fid + "_canview").attr("checked", obj.checked);
}
```

Note: This function can be freely used with passing 2 or 3 parameters (or really any number).

```
checkPermissions(1, this);        // Ok n === undefined 
checkPermissions(1, this, true);  // Ok n === true
checkPermissions(1);              // Okish n and obj === undefined
```

Comment: I mean , if the 'n' is defined in the function callback fe. checkPermissions(1, this, true) then the 3th param is a 'n' but I need also to use the same function at the same time without the n param : checkPermission(1, this)

Comment: Aight, now when I check my checkbox, firebug says that the checkPermission function is undefined. My onClick callback: `onClick="checkPermissions('.$gid.', this);"`

Comment: @Lucas, this is likely a separate issue due to the ordering of javascript code after the definition of the `onClick` handler.  You need to make sure the function is defined before the element to which you attach the handler

Comment: Thank you JaredPar, I got this working now. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkPermissions(fid, obj, n) {

    $("#permissions" + ((n) ? "Set" : "") + "_"+fid+"_canview").attr("checked", obj.checked);

}
```